# Change Username without changing home folder name MacOS

Tags: macos

I want to change the name of my username in MacOS, but not the home folder's name (I don't want my file paths, code to be disrupted). Is there a simple fix?

Comment: Do you want to change your "Full Name" (user-friendly name, usually with capital letters and space(s)) or the "Account Name" (usually lowercase, no spaces or punctuation)? Changing the Full Name is safe & easy, but changing the Account Name can have unexpected consequences, including losing admin privileges on the computer. See [this Apple.SE question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304640/changing-my-administrator-users-username-has-removed-privileges).

Comment: I just want to change the Full Name

Comment: See [Apple support document #HT201548: Change the name of your macOS user account and home folder](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548). Be sure not to change anything other than the Full name. Making sure you have a good backup of anything important *first* would be a good idea.